# How can I force Composer to check out the `master` branch?

Tags: git, composer-php

I'm having a problem where [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) sets a private package to no branch (`HEAD`) and it's only happening on packages which have tags.

When I require a private repository in Composer it looks like the below:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "vendorname/testbundle": "1.0.5"
},
"repositories": [
    { "type": "git", "url": "git@bitbucket.vendorname/testbundle.git" },
],
```

I have found that this is actually an expected behavior from Composer, but is there a way to force it to set to `master` branch?

**UPDATED**
I think that my current thoughts are a little bit diverted from the original question but I'm a beginner and I'm not sure if I fully understand composer behavior.

So, the scenario is:
I've develop a package lets say DemoPackage and created a dev and master branch. Dev would hold new features and when they stable I would merge them into master and tag that commit to mark certain changes. Few months later I've decided to completely rewrite that package so I would create a new branch v1 from the latest commit in master branch and started developing v2 in dev. But after another few months it turns out that I need to develop a new feature to the v1 branch and what I don't understand is if I'm going to add a new tag to branch v1 would composer find it if it's not in master branch?

Is the process I would follow OK?

Comment: You are requiring version 1.0.5, which contradicts your wish to require "dev-master".

Comment: Can I say that I'm looking for a tag from a specific branch? If that's not possible so how to achieve the below:

Comment: (follow up from previous comment)
I've got a package which has got new major release so version 1 is going to version 2. My thinking is that I would to create a branch which would hold version 1 and master would follow version 2. Let's say I have a bug in version 1 which I need to fix so I would apply that fix to branch v1, then I've got a change to do on v1 and I would like to add a tag to mark stable release. So my question is how to work with package which has 2 versions?

Comment: I think I still don't get it. Can you edit your question and describe in more detail what your situation is? A package with tagged version would be really easy to work with: Just require the versions, preferably with some kind of wildcard, like "1.0.*" or "~1.0" to allow for updates. What about the bugfixes? And is this package your own, or third party? Any way to send bug reports to fix it, or possibly pull requests?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to [change the requirements](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require):

```
php composer.phar require vendorname/testbundle:dev-master
```

> what I don't understand is if I'm going to add a new tag to branch v1 would composer find it if it's not in master branch?

It depends on how you specify the version in the `composer.json`:

- you can add new commits to the `v1` branch, and the require would still pick up the latest of `v1-dev`.
- Or you can put a tag on the latest commit of the updated `v1` branch and use that.

See "[Librarie: Specifying the version](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#specifying-the-version)".